# Use of Jni for native android development

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, java-native-interface

I´m pretty new on JNI programming and android programming and I want to use it on android ndk interfacing with kotlin for very large calculations. I am very experimented on C++ but not on JNI and languages that execute on JVM ...

Some of the questions are what happens to dynamic memory allocated on C++ side, I know the garbage collection utility but after created it manages thar memory or not ...

Second is can I trust on Swig for doing the wrapping tasks ? ... Third is can I do linux like network programming using socket.h ? if yes it exists some guidelines to do it ? ...

As I say I´m pretty new to this platform if someone could guide me it would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I suggest getting a book on JNI programming.  There are just too many details to getting a JNI application working properly.  Even if you're experienced, you need a JNI book or reference manual, just due to the complexity and the ease to get things wrong.

Comment: This is a good starting point https://www.protechtraining.com/content/java_fundamentals_tutorial-_java_native_interface_jni